# Sending a broadcast message to Google Home with an audio file

Tags: android, audio, google-home

I have an Android app that's capable of recording audio files.
I want to add a feature that lets my user pick an audio file and send it to Google Home as a broadcast (to all google home devices connected to my account)

Similar to the Google Assistant, if you say "Broadcast I love you all", all my Google Home devices will broadcast my audio message.

is there a way to send Google Home an audio file? some sort of Google Home API? Google Assistant API? anything that I can use to send a broadcast on my own?

I've searched online ofc, couldn't find anything that helped me.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you can't do it. 
It looks like something that you wish to avoid on the platform vis a vis abusive usage. 
However, with the upcoming features of [notifications/updates](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates) you could do something in the direction you are aiming.